# Win key rules for metro on Windows 8 RTM

Tags: windows-8

I'm having this problem with Windows 8 RTM and it's get annoying.

When I push the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key, I expect the Metro Start to pop-up on the monitor that my mouse is, but the Start appears on the last monitor that it has appeared before.

Even the Wi-Fi panel follows this rule, which is absurd since the Wi-Fi icon is far away, on the first monitor.

Is this controllable? Can I force the Start to open on the monitor my mouse is?

Comment: I think Start always appears on the main monitor.

Comment: No, it appears on the last monitor used by metro

Comment: Wow that's weird!. Following this question to find out if some day you can fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I use a product called [DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/) that makes working with multiple monitors much more friendly. It comes highly rated from a lot of people, including well-known Microsoft employees and MVPs. One of the options it has is to open the start menu/screen or launch apps on the monitor that the mouse currently occupies.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out, unfortunately the Window Location features are not available in the free version.